# Can not register with RHEL

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel5

```
# yum -v repolist
Loading "rhnplugin" plugin
Loading "security" plugin
Config time: 0.105
There was an error parsing the RHN proxy settings.
RHN support will be disabled.
Yum Version: 3.2.22
repolist: 0
```

and

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.18-164.el5 (mockbuild@x86-003.build.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)) #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009
```

and

```
# subscription-manager
-bash: subscription-manager: command not found
```

How do I register the system if I can not find or use subscription-manager?

Comment: Since you have a subscription (i.e. support) with RH, the best route would be to contact them.  If you have not purchased support, then you will not have access to the RH support site.  If all you want to use it RHEL without support, I'd strongly go to Centos which is real RHEL without some proprietary items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To register a system within RHN (assumed you have a valid subscription) you can use `rhn_register`. You have to provide your username and password from RHN.

Comment: Is there a way to register without user/password ? like accepting the system on the server side ? I'm trying to automate deployment and config of systems, and I'd really like not to store password in plain text ...